# flutter problem: My FAQs ui is not what I want

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

### I have this problem that I want to make my FAQs UI like Original UI but i cant making like that.

I have this problem that I want to make my FAQs UI like Original UI but i cant making like that.

I want like this UI.
[image]

But its creating like this.
[image]

My UI is not matching please help me How to make it like original.

This is my code.

```
import 'package:cwc/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../skeleton.dart';

class FAQPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return FAQPageState();
  }
}

class FAQPageState extends State<FAQPage> {
  bool isExpand = false;
  var selected;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    isExpand = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffffffff),
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.5,
        leading: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
              color: Colors.black,
              size: tSize24,
            )),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: isFAQLoading == true
          ? ButtonSkeleton()
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: faqListData.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                          offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
                          spreadRadius: 0.2)
                    ]),
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 0,
                      shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: 3,
                      ),
                      child: ExpansionTile(
                          key: Key(index.toString()),
                          backgroundColor: Color(0xfff6f7f9),
                          initiallyExpanded: index == selected,
                          iconColor: Colors.grey,
                          title: Text(
                            '${faqListData[index]['question']}',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xFF444444),
                                fontSize: tSize14,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                          ),
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 10.0, bottom: 10, left: 17, right: 17),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Text(
                                        "${faqListData[index]['answer']}",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Color(0xFF444444),
                                          fontSize: 13,
                                        ),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ))
                          ],
                          onExpansionChanged: ((newState) {
                            isExpand = newState;
                            print(newState);
                            if (newState)
                              setState(() {
                                Duration(seconds: 20000);
                                selected = index;
                                // isExpand=newState;
                              });
                            else
                              setState(() {
                                selected = -1;
                                // isExpand=newState;
                              });
                            print(selected);
                          })),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]);
              }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I checked your code and looks just small thing is missing. When you are passing key to the Exapnsion tile you need to pass same key to `ListView.builder` then it works fine.

```
       ListView.builder(
          key: Key('builder ${selected.toString()}'),
          itemCount: faqListData.length,
        ...
        ...
       );
```